# Do not use unique index in CosmosDB- MongoDB query - version 3.6

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I created a unique index of the fields below:

```
db.xpto.createIndex ({cod_id: 1, reg_id: 1}, {unique: true})



db.xpto.find ({cod_id: 1, reg_id: 2}). explain ()
```

of the message showing that it was not due to the index:

```
 query: {
       '$ and': [
         {cod_id: {'$ eq': 1}},
         {reg_id: {'$ eq': '2'}}
       ]
     },
     indexUsage: {
       pathsIndexed: {individualIndexes: [], compoundIndexes: []},
       pathsNotIndexed: {
         individualIndexes: ['cod_id', 'reg_id'],
         compoundIndexes: []
       }
     }
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: collection already has documents?

Comment: (Is the above a case of *question lost in translation*?) What, if anything, is the problem, and what is your programming question?

Comment: When I use the explain command, the query does not use an index and I want the query to be performed with an index?

Answer (score 0):

```
 db.xpto.insertOne({({cod_id: 1, reg_id: 1}});
 db.xpto.insertOne({({cod_id: 1, reg_id: 2}});
 db.xpto.insertOne({({cod_id: 1, reg_id: 3}});
 db.xpto.insertOne({({cod_id: 1, reg_id: 4}});
```

How i do to use index? how do I force an index on mongodb?